# My For-loop inserts xml data in the wrong place

Tags: c#, xml, for-loop, xml-parsing

(I don't know exactly what my problem is so I hope I asked it with the right tags and title)
When I get my xml file and let the for-loop start it does this

1 (x breakpoint before error )(locals)

```
    name    "0" string
    enetSportCode   "1.0"   string
x   del "2011-03-15 13:53:12"   string
    n   0   int
    ut  null    string
    sportid 0   int
```

which after that I get the error
"input string was not in a correct format"
so I do know n gets a value that is not a int 
but if I would make it a string this will happen

2 (x breakpoint before error )(locals)

```
    name    "0" string
    enetSportCode   "1.0"   string
    del "2011-03-15 13:53:12"   string
x   n   "0.171" string
    ut  null    string
    sportid 0   int
```

the error this time is 
"index was outside the bounds of the array"
I do not know why it does that but it should have done this instead

```
    name    "Soccer"    string
    enetSportCode   "s" string
    del "no"    string
    n   "1" int
    ut  "2009-12-29 15:36:24"   string
    sportid "1" int
```

this is the code that I use
C# part

```
private void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Stream xmlStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFile1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFile1.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFile1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFile1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((xmlStream = openFile1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (xmlStream)
                    {
                        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Database=;Server=;Integrated Security=True;connect timeout = 30");
                        SqlCommand command;
                        SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        XmlReader xmlFile ;
                        string sql;
                        string name;
                        string enetSportCode;
                        string del;
                        int n;
                        string ut;
                        int sportid;

                        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(openFile1.FileName, new XmlReaderSettings());
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                        int i = 0;
                        int j = 0;
                        myConnection.Open();
                        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[j].Rows.Count; i++)

                        {
                            name = ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                            enetSportCode = ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                            del = ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                            n = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
                            ut = ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                            sportid = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[5]);
                            sql = "insert into sports('" + name + "','" + enetSportCode + "','" + del + "'," + n + ",'" + ut + "'," + sportid + ")";
                            command = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
                            adpter.InsertCommand = command;
                            adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        myConnection.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("complete");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

xml part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spocosy version="1.0" responsetime="2011-03-15 13:53:12" exec="0.171">
<query-response requestid="" service="objectquery">
<sport>
    <sport name="Soccer" enetSportCode="s" del="no" n="1" ut="2009-12-29 15:36:24" id="1"/>
</sport>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Because parsing XML using a `DataSet` is likely not the best way to do this.  Have you looked at LINQ to XML?

Comment: It looks really awkward to do it that way...

Comment: Your dataset contains four tables (spocosy, query0response", query-response", sort).  The code is trying to assign 0.171 to n which is an integer and giving an error.

Comment: @CharlesMager
I am trying to insert xml data into a database trough C# 
(while I have yet to do this I also try to make it prevent inserting wrong/duplicate data into the database)

I have not looked into LINQ yet but I will do that on a later note
For now I want to know why the data acted the way it did

Comment: How is an NULL attribute placed in the XML?

Comment: @SakoArorim, i changed my answer

Comment: @Schuere  
(in case you did not read the comment on your answer)
I am sorry for the confusion I thought it would been helpful if I placed the whole array even after the pointbreak happened  which is why it was still NULL at that point of time cause it had yet to get a value from the XML but seeing as C# crashed before that due to the errors ut never received one
also thanks for the update as well I learned from it but the old answer was the more helpfull one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I continue, I made a small alteration to you xml structure:
adding closing tags for spocosy and query-response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spocosy version="1.0" responsetime="2011-03-15 13:53:12" exec="0.171">
<query-response requestid="" service="objectquery">
<sport>
    <sport name="Soccer" enetSportCode="s" del="no" n="1" ut="2009-12-29 15:36:24" id="1"/>
</sport>
</query-response>
</spocosy>
```

Firstly, you need to make sure all you attributes are available. The fact that you receive a 'index was outside the bounds of the array' error tells us one or more of your attributes is missing. When this occurs you have 5 or less attributes so when asking for 'ItemArray[5]' will defenitily raise an error

How to catch this? Make your xml attributes Obligated OR use the attribute names instead of an array value. This means change the code or make validations before handling anything.

ie: ds.Rows[j].ItemArray.Count < 6 => Throw: Missing attribute

How to catch the 0.172? Change

```
sportid = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[5])
```

to

```
sportid = Int.TryParse(ds.Tables[j].Rows[i].ItemArray[5], out sportid) ? sportid : 0;
```

**OLD ANSWER IN LINQ**

Then: let us use Linq:

```
//Load xml
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

//Run query
var sports = from sport in xdoc.Descendants("spocosy")
                 .Descendants("query-response")
                      .Descendants("sport")
                           .Descendants("sport")
             select new { 
               Name= sport.Attribute("name").Value,
               EnetSportCode = sport.Attribute("enetSportCode").Value,
               Del = sport.Attribute("del").Value,
               N = Convert.ToInt32(sport.Attribute("n").Value),
               UT = sport.Attribute("ut").Value,
               SportId = Convert.ToInt32(sport.Attribute("id").Value)
               };

var sqlLines = new List<string>();
//Loop through results
foreach (var sport in sports)
{ 
    sqlLines.Add(string.Format("Insert into sports(NameColumn, EnetSportCodeColumn, DelColumn, nColumn, utColumn, sportidColumn) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3}, '{4}', {5})", 
            sport.Name, 
            sport.EnetSportCode, 
            sport.Del, 
            sport.N, 
            sport.UT, 
            sport.SportId));
}
```

Also: The correct syntax for inserting is:

```
Insert into TableName
(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC)
VALUES
(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC)
```

**NOT**

```
Insert Into TableName
(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC)
```

EDIT: Also another remark: inserting the DOUBLE/DECIMAL/FLOAT value 0.172 inside an INT based column will not work. Even more, it will generate an error at the line Convert.ToInt32()...

EDIT2: How do you receive an NULL value inside your xml? is the attribute abscent/ is it just "" ?

Comment: Thanks ^_^ You have helped me a lot and in just a few minutes you and jdweng figured out my problem and here I was trying to find out why I had this problem for about 12 hours :[

For some reason I just assumed <Sport> was the first one which is why I was so confused as to why I got those value instead of the value I wanted 

I did not receive a NULL value the X stands for the breakpoint everything below that is what I saw in the locals and have yet to receive a value (if C# would not have crashed after the X point)

Comment: @SakoArorim, glad we could help you